# How to hide the name of the file (e.g. "index.html") in a website and work with sections?

Tags: html, css, url

I need to create a single-page website using HTML5, which is similar to 
http://www.20thingsilearned.com

It uses "Sections" in HTML5 as shown below:

http://www.20thingsilearned.com/en-US/web-apps/1

When I create a page index.html with the sections named: foreword, credits, etc ...
I can access the page by: http://localhost:2325/index.html
and the sections by:

http://localhost:2325/index.html/foreword, unlike the above shown website!!
can you please suggest a solution?

further clarification:
Is it possible to do this via JS??

Comment: Isn't this usually done by using ASP.NET MVC? Or PHP?

Comment: Have a look at http://html5demos.com/history.

Comment: how does the html5demos.com/history do it??
using server side technology??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition/convention, you can access your page with http://localhost:2325/
If a file isn't specified (which is explicit with the trailing slash), the server provides by default the index.html file.
This default can be changed with the server's settings, I think.

I might have misunderstood the last part, but in general, one accesses the sections with the http://localhost:2325/#forword syntax, instead. The # says to jump to the named section.

Stuff like web-apps/1 is generally handled by a server-side script (PHP, ASP or other) along with rewrite rules, redirecting such URL to a script serving the correct content.

Comment: is there anyway to do it without ServerSide code??
also, i don't want to go to another, but stay on the same page and just make the appropriate section visible ...

Comment: As shown in the above comments, this can be done also with JavaScript, but if all you want is to jump to a given section in the same page, just use the `<a name="someId"></a>` reference and jump to it with `<a href="#someId">Go to a section</a>` code.

Comment: where is it mentioned, how to do that with JS??

Answer (score 0):

The above can be achieved by using URL rewriting and JS History api.

Since then, I've learnt about URL rewriting and also the usage of route-tables in ASP.NET WebForms 4.

Great link for url rewriting, which mentions the redirect rule for default page as well:
syedemad.info/index.php/2012/02/url-rewriting-tips/